# What friends are listening to not showing up

Tags: ios, icloud, apple-music

I don't have that option on phone, windows itunes, macos music app. Sync Library is on but not showing up. As you see in the photo, Apple says tap to "See What Friends Are Listening To" but I don't have that option on Apple Music app. So I can't create a social profile on Apple Music.

How can I add friends to my iTunes Music subscription so I can see what they are playing and get a weekly friends mix added to my iPhone and subscription?

[image]

Comment: Please understand, we're not there seeing what you're seeing.  I'm sure there's an issue that's frustrating you, but from where we're sitting on the other side of your screen, we don't know what it is.  Please take a moment to review [How to Ask a Good Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips on writing a question that will help you get the answer(s) you're looking for.

Comment: I’ve edited this. Can we assume you followed this article in setting up friends? https://www.imore.com/how-follow-friends-and-find-new-ones-apple-music

Comment: If you follow the instructions linked in the comment above, where do things start to work differnetly than expected?

Comment: I can't follow the instructions because I have to set what friends are listening to first.

Comment: You can't see what your friends are listening to until you set up your own profile.  Did you set it up already?  See:  https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/see-what-your-friends-are-listening-to-iphdf490a9e9/ios

Comment: Yes, I set it up when Apple Music released. But there is no "View Profile" too. By the way I use iOS 13.4.1.

Comment: So when you pull down on the screen your screenshot shows, you don't get a profile on top?

Comment: No, I don't get.

Comment: Still same, can't find a solution about it.